# How to set the data rapidly in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a junior developer in the HR system.

Let's assume the below.
There are two sheets 'A' and 'B'.
I want to copy the contents of 'B' to 'A'.
So I selected the method using getRange, getValues, setValue.. etc.
The method was successful, but the processing speed failed.
The speed was very very slow.

How can I set the data more rapidly?

I wrote the code below.
Please help me with your advice!

```
function setList(){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  fromSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('B');
  toSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('A');

  var arry = fromSheet.getRange('A1:M239').getValues();
  Logger.log(arry);

  var lastRow = fromSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = fromSheet.getLastColumn();

  for (var j = 2; j< lastRow; j++){
    for (var i = 1; i < lastCol; i++){
      toSheet.getRange(usedRow + 1,i).setValue(fromSheet.getRange(usedRow + 1,i).getValue());
      }
    usedRow++; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track at first with `getValues()` but then you did each cell individually with `getValue()/setValue()`.  Since you want to copy all the values from `fromSheet` to `toSheet` just use 1 `setValues()`.

```
function setList(){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  fromSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('B');
  toSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('A');

  var arry = fromSheet.getRange('A1:M239').getValues();
  Logger.log(arry);
  array.shift(); // remove the headers

  // you don't define usedRow so I'm assuming its the same row as fromSheet
  toSheet.getRange(2,1,arry.length,arry[0].length).setValues(arry);
}
```

Reference

- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Wow,, Thank you for your favor!
I completed my code thanks for your help.
Have a nice day!